# cp: cannot stat 'AmritaAura_local/amrita_aura/aura': No such file or directory

Tags: python, file, virtualenv, cp, stat

When I try to copy the files in virtual environment I get the above error.The command is cp -r AmritaAura_local/amrita_aura/aura  AmritaAura_local/local_setup/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages.
Where am I going wrong ? What does the error indicate in python?What does cannot stat means ?

Answer (score 0):

Proper path name should be given in destination directory and also the location of source directory should be opened in terminal.Then cp -r src_directory(only the relative path) destination_directory(full path) should be given.